# Removing a duplicated coordinate in multipoints using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have shapefile river data in line format, import this data with GeoPandas and apply it to a `.boundary` to get as initial and final coordinates of each line. But as lines intersect a coordinate may appear more than once.

How to remove all duplicated coordinates?

The code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
data=gpd.read_file('/home/user/projetos/data/shapefile/drenagem.shp')
points = data.boundary
points

0      (POINT (333491.5480657421 9655087.635814797), ...
1      (POINT (341810.8488631362 9644289.599092623), ...
2      (POINT (313337.5609903137 9683542.660879284), ...
3      (POINT (338807.641063218 9648943.660769818), P...
4      (POINT (338695.3584550109 9649099.693239413), ...
5      (POINT (338416.3272727653 9651639.210259687), ...
6      (POINT (338365.4593791683 9651724.896800613), ...
7      (POINT (337887.8405421138 9652423.9019504), PO...
8      (POINT (337419.4672116803 9653120.853008965), ...

points[0]

MULTIPOINT (333491.5480657421 9655087.635814797, 337419.4672116803 9653120.853008965)
```

Comment: look at [drop_duplicates functionality](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/521)